# How to pass an ArrayList to the StartActivityForResult activity

Tags: java, android

I need to from Activity A start an Activity B for result. I need to pass a String ArrayList  from Activity A to Activity B first. I thought that this code would work but it crashes the app with a message that the list was not passed:

Activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PopUpRunda.class);
Bundle sendList = new Bundle();
sendList.putStringArrayList("list",listA);
startActivityForResult(intent,2,sendList);
```

Activity B:

```
Bundle gotList = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> listB = gotList.getStringArrayList("list");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PopUpRunda.class);
Bundle sendList = new Bundle();
sendList.putStringArrayList("list",listA);
startActivityForResult(intent,2,sendList);
```

with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PopUpRunda.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list",listA);
startActivityForResult(intent,2);
```

The `Bundle` that is available as a parameter on `startActivityForResult()` is not how you pass `Intent` extras.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :)